# Parsing a slash and apostrophe with Python regex

Tags: sql, regex

I am attempting to parse a Wikipedia SQL dump with the Python regular expressions library.  The ultimate goal is to import this dump into PostgreSQL, but I know the apostrophes in strings need to be doubled, beforehand.

Every apostrophe in a string in this dump is preceded by a backwards slash, though, and I'd rather not remove the backwards slashes.

> (42,'Thirty_Years\'_War',33,5,0,0)

Using the command

```
re.match(".*?([\w]+?'[\w\s]+?).*?", line)
```

I cannot identify the apostrophe in the middle of 'Thirty_Years\'_War', when 'line' is parsed from a text file.

For comparison, these lines work fine when parsed (sans the last line).

> The person's car
>
> The person's car's gasoline
>
> Hodges' Harbrace Handbook
>
> 'Hodges' Harbrace Handbook'
>
> portspeople',1475,29,0,0),(42,'Thirty_Years\'_War',33,5,0,0)

Correct and expected output (sans the last line):

> The person''s car
>
> The person''s car''s gasoline
>
> Hodges'' Harbrace Handbook
>
> ('Hodges'' Harbrace Handbook')
>
> portspeople',1475,29,0,0),(42,'Thirty_Years\'_War',33,5,0,0)

Using the command

```
re.match(".*?([\w\\]+?'[\w\s]+?).*?", line)
```

breaks it.

> The person''s car
>
> The person''''s car''''s gasoline
>
> Hodges'' Harbrace Handbook
>
> (''''''''Hodges'''''''' Harbrace Handbook'''''''')
>
> portspeople'''''''''''''''',1475,29,0,0),(42,''''''''''''''''Thirty_Years\''''''''''''''''_War'''''''''''''''',33,5,0,0)

Is it stuck in some sort sort of loop?  What is the correct regex code to use?

I am not thinking about SQL injection attacks because this script is only going to be used for parsing dumps of Wikipedia articles (that don't contain examples of SQL injection attacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dump consists of things like the string you provided, you could try something like this:

```
re.findall(r"[^,\(\)]+")
```

Where the character class contains all known separators.

EDIT: Only use regex for parsing when there is no better way :)

Comment: Including the 'r' prefix fixed it.
"String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences."

I'd have to change that regex code slightly to group the apostrophe and its surrounding letters, right?

Why only use regex as a last resort?  Thanks

Comment: Good stuff. The regex I gave will capture anything that's a group of characters not in the class. You might run into issues with commas in strings perhaps. Regex is good for partial string pattern matching but for parsing a structured document chances are there's a parser built to support the syntax full. Any solution with regex will likely do a good job but not a perfect one. For instance, it's cleaner using an XML parser than regex since it'll support nested tags and all the markup rules.

Answer (score 0):

Most Python database interfaces will take care of quoting SQL statements for you.  For example, with the [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/) driver, you would write something like:

```
mystring="""This is 'a string' that contains single quotes."""
c.execute('INSERT INTO mytable (mycolumn) VALUES (%s)', mystring)
```

...and the database driver will take care of correctly quoting the values for you.  Look at some of the examples [in the documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).  In fact, their first example is remarkably like this one.

Comment: I should have made it more clear that the script writes another copy of the SQL dump to an SQL file, with apostrophes fixed.  Psycopg actually isn't a part of this.  But this is an alternative way of importing an SQL dump.